# Z-Index seemingly having no effect

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a box that has a border with a triangle coming out the bottom. An example of this can be seen in the reviews section of this page: http://www.browserstack.com/

I have created my triangle image to overlay on top of the box to create the effect, but I'm having trouble getting it to sit on top of the box.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="box">...</div>
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.box {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul li.active {
        background: url("testimonial-triangle.png") no-repeat scroll 108px -1px transparent;
}
```

As you can see, I've attempted to set the .box div and the UL LI to have relative positioning and given the UL LI a greater z-index, but this doesn't seem to be doing anything.

EDIT: I've also tried putting the positioning and z-index on the UL instead of the LI, but this doesn't seem to be doing anything either. Here's the CSS I tried:

```
.box {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul li {}

ul li.active {
        background: url("testimonial-triangle.png") no-repeat scroll 108px -1px transparent;
}
```

Comment: z-index works well with position: absolute;

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can use absolute positioning in this case.

Comment: Yes You Can, If you try to put all code in proper hierarchy.

Comment: It will be extremely difficult to manage in this case as the site is responsive all the way down to mobile with lots of variations of the layout, so positioning the UL or list items absolutely will be hard to do.

Comment: Don't seem any other option then. you can refer opacity and transparent tags though.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the elements are not on the same level in the DOM. You have to put the z-index to the `<UL>` element ... not to the `<LI>`.

Comment: Okay, I took the position and z-index from the li and put it on the ul, but still no effect. :/